# Error using "if" in R: "== : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" for spTransform

Tags: r, sp

I am trying to make the projection of a set of coordinates identical to a shape from wrld_simpl. But I keep getting the error below. How to solve that?

```
d=read.csv()
it= wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$NAME == "Italy", ]  
d=na.omit(d)
d1=d[,c("lon","lat")]
coordinates(d1)=~lon+lat
d1=spTransform(d1,CRSobj="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
+no_defs")
```

Error in if (is.projected(obj)) { :
valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
Además: Warning message:
In spTransform(xSP, CRSobj, ...) :
NULL source CRS comment, falling back to PROJ string

Comment: here is the link to the file for a reproducible example: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/wm0wok1f12ucjy3gw7ep2/Book2.csv?rlkey=v9cwd15hrhccx9pvee2lrnnq9&dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few problems here: `d1` at the error point has an `NA` (missing) CRS so any attempt to reproject it with `spTransform` will fail.

On my system it fails with a different error message:

```
> d1=spTransform(d1,CRSobj="+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs") 
Error in st_transform.sfc(st_geometry(x), crs, ...) : 
  cannot transform sfc object with missing crs
```

which makes me think you have an old version of `sp`.

To assign a CRS to an `sp` object you can use `proj4string(d1) <-`  like:

```
proj4string(d1)  <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs"
```

this is telling `sp` what coordinate system the numbers are. Since they look like lat-long WGS84 coordinates, I've used the proj4string you've got from the world map. At this point you should be able to plot them both with no more transformation needed:

```
> plot(it)
> plot(d1, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

If I plot the whole of the points and add the world it looks like everything lines up:

```
> plot(d1)
> plot(wrld_simpl, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

The other problem is that the `sp` package is deprecated and you should look at using the `sf` package and its data structures instead.

Comment: Thank you @spacedman! It seems I will have to stop delaying that shift to sf in my scripts.